# "Home Server" + XBMC

Tags: kodi, server

I would like to setup a RaspberryPi "Home Server" + XBMC. I would install services such as SSH Server, VPN Server (openvpn or ppp), DLNA Server (miniDLNA), SAMBA Server and Transmission-daemon, all of them running 24/7. XBMC would start only when i press specific button on tv remote (TV connected by HDMI, CEC available).
Is this setup possible? What OS should i use?! Raspbian + XBMC, Raspbmc or XBian?

Comment: been there, done that. in the end, you're going to need two RPi, one as xbmc player, another one as file server and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with @lenik's comments and have two.  I tried to use an XBMC distro to do extra things and it struggled under the load.  Additionally, there's a chance that as you play around with it to get all the other services running, you might just break it (like I did!).  If anyone else is relying on your RPi for their entertainment, they'll be severely disappointed.

Why not run `OpenELEC` on one Pi, which is designed as a stand-alone appliance and therefore not that easy to fiddle with.  Then get another Pi for your server and install one of the mainstream distros on it.  You could network share the media between the two Pis.

Comment: I agree with you @garethTheRed about the performance. I just think all these services will be rarely used.

If he needs a RPi to play around, I also agree he shouldn't use the same for media server.

And once you have a reliable storage (good quality and well maintained SD card or external Hard Drive) it's ok. Ah, as I said, the good source power supply is very important. It reflects in the hardware over time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.
The more services you add, the slower your systems gets. Do you really need all of this?

The easiest path is [Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/) which already includes many of these softwares.
I also recommend to buy a good quality SD card and source power supply if you will let it on all the time.

For the remote control, take a look at [lirc](http://www.lirc.org/) project.

If you have any further question, let me know.